# On Checking Check Box Get the child Object Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

[image]

I want to achieve a scenario in which when i click TV1 radiobutton i want to get all of its children in the object i.e ProductName TV1, Number Of Channels 1 . Below is my code

**Markup :**

```
<div ng-repeat="product in ProductTypes">         
    <div ng-show="product.selected" ng-repeat="Product in product.ProductList">
      <label>
           <input type="radio" name="internetProduct{{$parent.$index}}"
               ng-model="Product" ng-value="{{Product}}" ng-click="GetValue()" />
            {{Product.ProductName}}
      </label>

      <table>
         <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in Product">
            <td>{{key}}</td>
            <td>{{val}}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>

   </div>
</div>
```

**Controller (js) :**

```
var app = angular.module('ProductCatalog.controllers', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('OfferCtrlr', function ($scope, $http, $modal) {
      $scope.GetValue = function() {
        var a = $scope.radio;
    }
})
```

Right now, nothing is coming in $scope.radio. Please helpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the product instance to your ng-click function call as a parameter. So whenever the radio button is clicked, the corresponding product instance will be available inside your function. The below code will give you the instance for radio button. Do the same thing for checkbox, call a function on checking and pass the corresponding instance.(you have not provided the markup for checkbox)

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in ProductTypes">         
    <div ng-show="product.selected" ng-repeat="Product in product.ProductList">
      <label>
           <input type="radio" name="internetProduct{{$parent.$index}}"
               ng-model="checked" ng-value="Product" ng-click="GetValue(Product)" />
            {{Product.ProductName}}
      </label>

      <table>
         <tr ng-repeat="(key, val) in Product">
            <td>{{key}}</td>
            <td>{{val}}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>

   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('ProductCatalog.controllers', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('OfferCtrlr', function ($scope, $http, $modal) {
      $scope.GetValue = function(product) {
        console.log(product);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Load all the parent and child objects then show/hide through the AngularJS, through that you will achieve your scenario.